# How to internationalize ReactJS Web Application including Arabic language?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl, formatjs

Looking for something compatible with **ReactJS** to make my Web Application multilingual along with RTL to LTR and vice-versa.

As per my research, I found NPM package called **"react-intl"** backed by Yahoo using [FormatJS](http://formatjs.io) is relevant solution. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl

**Is that reliable to use for Arabic language as well?**

**Do you know any other stable and scalable solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, That's perfect you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl
for Internationalization in React.
Also I did using above npm in Arabic, Hindi, Spanish.
Go through this link(https://medium.freecodecamp.org/internationalization-in-react-7264738274a0) which is helpful.

Comment: This is very useful.
Also, May I know have you developed OR delivered similar Web Application in ReactJS? If yes, it would be great if you can share URL.

Answer (score 0):

I use react.i18next specially when i'm using react hooks
here's a good step by step guid  [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook)